# how to create a line chart of quartiles for each type

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, linechart

I have a dataframe with types and sales.
types column contains 6 different types. I used this code to get this output: `df.groupby('Types')['Sales'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])`

```
Type 1               0.25    510.0
                     0.50    600.0
                     0.75    680.0
Type 2               0.25    280.0
                     0.50    370.0
                     0.75    500.0
Type 3               0.25    410.0
                     0.50    550.0
                     0.75    660.0
Type 4               0.25    400.0
                     0.50    520.0
                     0.75    630.0
Type 5               0.25    240.0
                     0.50    310.0
                     0.75    460.0
Type 6               0.25    650.0
                     0.50    750.0
                     0.75    800.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Now, what  I want to do is create a line chart. It should display quartiles of sales for each type. This line chart will have 3 lines, one for each quartile.

Comment: `df.groupby('Types')['Sales'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75]).unstack().plot()`.

Comment: I got an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: My mistake, it's `unstack`. Updated.

Comment: It works but can I adjust this plot. Its a lil bit small.

Comment: Pass `figsize=(12,6)` to `plot()`. You can play with the numbers.

Comment: sorry i couldnt understand. How am i going to do that? Should i add figsize to end of the ..unstack().plot() code or should i call it before the code?

Comment: `.unstack().plot(figsize=(12,6))`....